# Do the children in a Shopify bulk operation JSONL with nested connections come right after their parent?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

When parsing a bulk operation JSONL file with nested items from top to bottom line by line, when I reach a new top level parent object, does that mean I've gone through all children of the previous parent?

**Context**

When processing a bulk operation JSONL file, I do some processing that requires having a parent and all of their children. I'd like to keep my memory requirements as small as possible, so I need to know when I'm done processing an object and all of its children.

**Example for clarification**

Using the [documentation page's](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries#the-jsonl-data-format) JSONL example:

```json
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435458986123","title":"52","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435458986040","title":"70","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569259576"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459018808","title":"34","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569259576"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569292344"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459051576","title":"Default Title","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569292344"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569325112"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459084344","title":"36","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569325112"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569357880"}
{"id":"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/19435459117112","title":"47","__parentId":"gid://shopify/Product/1921569357880"}
```

If I'm reading the file line by line from top to bottom and I hit Product with id `gid://shopify/Product/1921569259576` on line 4, does this mean that I've already seen all of the previous product's (`gid://shopify/Product/1921569226808`) product variants the JSONL file contains?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely assume that the children of a parent will be directly under it. The documentation is indeed vague on this:

> The GraphQL Admin API doesn't serially process the contents of the JSONL file. Avoid relying on a particular sequence of lines and object order to achieve a desired result.

But that refers to the fact that parents can appear in a different order and that the children can have an inconsistent order. For example, if you have 10 variants, they can appear in a different order but strictly under their parent.

If the Bulk API did not give any guarantees regarding the children it would have been impossible to read large files because expecting a child to appear anywhere within a file would mean that you need to keep all parsed objects in memory until you read the last line.

Answer (score -1):

What a lot of people do is shell out and use tac to reverse the file. Then when you parse the file you end up nice processing the children first and then knowing when you hit the parent, you have everything and you can move.

Obviously this is nicer than getting the parent and then the children, and then wondering, have I hit all the children or are there more.

Try it! It works!

My pseudo code (which you can convert to whatever scripting language you want looks like this:

```html
inventory_file = Tempfile.new
inventory_file.binmode
uri = URI(result.data.node.url)
IO.copy_stream(uri.open, inventory_file) # store large amount of JSON Lines data in a tempfile
inventory_file.rewind # move from EOF to beginning of file
y = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{shop_domain}.reversed.jsonl"
`tac #{inventory_file.path} > #{y}`
puts "Completed Reversal of file using tac, so now we can quickly iterate the inventory"
f = File.foreach(y)
variants = {}
f.each_entry do |line|
  data = JSON.parse(line)
  # play with my data
end
```

Comment: Does that mean that some children may come after another top level parent in the JSONL file? The documentation isn't so clear on this

Comment: If the results aren't potentially interleaved, I'm not seeing the value in reading the file in reverse. If I'm reading the file top to bottom, when I hit the next parent, wouldn't this mean that at this point I'm guaranteed to have seen all of the previous parent's children?

Comment: I am in no position to affect your thinking. Since it is nothing but CPU time, do whatever you think is best for you. I just showed you what is considered the superior parsing pattern, and while I never explained why it is superior, I leave that exercise to you. You are free to ignore it, and just parse as you wish.

Comment: Are you able to explain why you believe reverse processing is superior? The question asks for clarity on the nature of the Shopify JSONL file.

Parsing the file in reverse would be beneficial if the following is true about Shopify bulk operation JSONL files: (1) children always come after their parent and (2) other objects may be interleaved while still respecting (1). Example. if a JSONL file can come in this order: Product1, Product2, Product1Variant1, Product2Variant1, then going in reverse is preferable since once I hit Product2, I know that I've seen all its variants.

Comment: All I did was answer your question and give you a trick. The rest is up to you.

Comment: @DavidLazar, I believe you did not answer the question. The question was can you trust that all children of a parent are guaranteed to be directly after their parent or there is a possibility that a child of a parent can be further down the file (after some other parent)? Your answer was more about the efficiency and ease of parsing rather than the guarantees of the Bulk API.

Comment: inspect for the child parent keys, and you clearly you could write a parser you'd trust at 100%, no matter the mess Shopify used. Luckily, they provide sensible data output.